# Can I use two different forms in one module?

Tags: forms

I'm new to Drupal 8 and I was wondering if I can use two forms which are inside the Form folder(mymodule/src/Form/). The name of my forms are FormOne.php and FormTwo.php.

I can only display and use FormOne.php through my entire module.

I have researched it and can't find an answer.

Can you help me on displaying the second form?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can define as many forms in a module as you need.

If you want to include two forms into one page, you can do so by using the form builder in your controller to call both forms and build a render array.

Instead of using `_form` in your `*.routing.yml` file, you would instead use `_controller`, and define a controller callback rather than a form callback. Your controller would then be something like this:

```
class ExampleController extends Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase {

  function examplePageCallback() {
    // Note - you should use dependency injection to inject this service, 
    // rather than this method.
    $form_builder = \Drupal::service('form_builder');

    $return [
      'form_a' => $form_builder->getForm('Drupal\[MODULE]\Form\FormA'),
      'form_b' => $form_builder->getForm('Drupal\[MODULE]\Form\FormB'),
    ];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, @Jaypan. I asked this question because I noticed that the FormOne can only be used and display. It seems that I can't use and display FormTwo. Should I declare each form in the routing.yml?

Comment: If you want the form to be accessible at a route, yes, that is one way you can use the second form.

Comment: Is it possible to add both routes in the routing.yml?

`mymodule.display_form:`
`       path: '/mymodule'`
`      defaults:`
`                _form: '\Drupal\mymodule\Form\FormOne'`
`                _form: '\Drupal\mymodule\Form\FormTwo'`

Comment: You need to build a controller that returns a render array containing both forms in that case.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Jaypan, thanks for the update. I am planning to use each form in a separate page. Is it also possible?

Comment: Yes, in that case you would use the method Razeem has posted as an answer. His answer is how to have separate pages for each form. My answer is how to have two forms on one page.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. @Jaypan

Comment: You should mark his answer as correct, but give both of us an upvote for our answers. That's the custom here :) Welcome.

Comment: Sure @Jaypan, both answers are helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you also @Kevin for the additional info

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom Form in `MyCustomFormA.php`

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\MY_MODULE\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Class MyCustomFormA.
 */
class MyCustomFormA extends FormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'my_custom_form_a';
  }
.....
}
```

Same way you can create another Form in `MyCustomFormB.php`

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\MY_MODULE\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Class MyCustomFormB.
 */
class MyCustomFormB extends FormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'my_custom_form_b';
  }
....
}
```

In your `MY_MODULE.routing.yml`

```
MY_MODULE.my_custom_form_a:
  path: '/MY_MODULE/my_custom_form_a'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\MY_MODULE\Form\MyCustomFormA'
    _title: 'My Custom Form A Form'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
MY_MODULE.my_custom_form_b:
  path: '/MY_MODULE/my_custom_form_b'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\MY_MODULE\Form\MyCustomFormB'
    _title: 'My Custom Form B Form'

  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, @Razeem. For the `MyCustomFormB.php`, should I also declare it on the routing.yml?

Comment: If you wan to display it in a specific page then yes

Comment: do you need `requirements` in each form. It gives me an 'HTTP ERROR 500'. I also tried to clear cache and it gives me the same error.

Comment: yes you may also add that

Comment: Thank you so much @Razeem

Comment: Welcome @JeirodAbogado.